# Z-index on borders

Tags: css, border, z-index

I have been searching around for a way to add z-index to borders but can't seem to find one so I thought I'd ask here.

Say I have a div with a parent div. The parent has a border and I want that border to overlap the child div but I don't want the parent to overlap it.

Comment: You can't do that. Why can't you set the border on child div? There is for sure a way to achieve the desired output. Please expand your request with more details.

Answer (score 39):

You cannot do that with a border.

Interestingly though, you **can** do it with an `outline`

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 25px auto;
position: relative;
background: #bada55;
border:12px solid #663399;
outline: 12px solid red;
padding:25px
 }

.child {
width: 220px;
height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Other Options**

Using pseudo-elements

*1. Pseudo-element with border*

Requires some additional transforms to nudge into place.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #bada55;
  padding: 25px;
}
.child {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.absolute::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 12px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent absolute">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

*2. Pseudo-element with box-shadow*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #bada55;
  padding: 25px;
}
.child {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.shadow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent shadow">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Paulie_D - awesome answer

Comment: Unfortunate that there is no outline-bottom, outline-right, etc.

Comment: Thanks, outline did the trick for me! By the way @RaisinBranCrunch, you can use margin to hide the outline on the sides you don't want.

Comment: This is good solution however there is no radius for outline for most of the browser - only FF support -moz-outline-radius

Answer (score 5):

## style border on pseudo element

1. for higher z-index use pseudo element eg. `::before`
2. to be able to interact with div under - use `pointer-events: none;` on the pseudo element (see [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events))

important part of code:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
.parent::before {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    ...
}
```

full example: https://codepen.io/Michal-Miky-Jankovsky/pen/QoXbLz

Answer (score -1):

Obligatory *"I see you want to solve this by solution A. Solution A is bad. Here is solution B instead."*

In short, I would recommend:

1. Pseudo elements:

   A. `.my-div searched-element:nth-of-type(1)` (i.e. `searched-element` would be `p` or `h1` or `div`)

   B. `:first-child`

   C. `:first-of-type`

   D. `:last-child`
2. `margin-top: -10px` such that the child will  be moved up

   **And the real solution I would recommend** is using the negative top margin of the child with some variants of the `:first-child` pseudo classes.

**For my case specifically**, I actually found it easier to switch my borders from `border-top` to `border-bottom` on all of the child divs and then use `:last-child` within that scope.